# switching command based on node env variable for the docker-compose.yml file

Tags: node.js, docker

I am trying to host an application, so I have created a server and a client folder. In server folder node js and client its react using create-react-app.

So for docker, I have created two Dockerfile in server and client folder. In the project root created a docker-compose.yml file.

for local development, I need to have the auto reloading capability for the server so, I have put

`command: nodemon index.js`

in the docker-compose.yml file. Everything is working fine. when i build the docker. But when I host this application I need to change to

```
`command: node index.js`
```

The only way I think it will add a node environment variable when I host the application, but the problem is I can access in the index.js of server folder like

```
process.env.APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT
```

but how can I access in the docker-compose.yml file? Since I want to use the same docker-compose.yml file for hosting and make developer to start work easily by having the capability of server auto reloading.

Is there any other better way to do this. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`docker-compose` files support [variable substitution](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution). You can then use this to store and set the command you want to run directly in the `docker-compose` file.

E.g a sample `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3"
services:
  server:
    build: ./server
    command: ${NODE_COMMAND:-nodemon} index.js
```

`${NODE_COMMAND:-nodemon}` will default to `nodemon` if no `NODE_COMMAND` variable is present in your shell. You can override this value in production by providing a value for `NODE_COMMAND` when you start the containers i.e :

`$ NODE_COMMAND=node docker-compose up -d`

Alternatively, on your hosted server you could create a `.env` file in the same directory that you run your `docker-compose` commands like so:

```
NODE_COMMAND=node
```

And `docker-compose` will automatically substitute the value in your compose file. See the linked page about variable substitution for more details.

Hopefully this helps.